# Part 36 offer forms, sent to whom?

Tags: united-kingdom, process

When a defendant is making a Part 36 offer (using form N242A) to whom are they (or their solicitor) required to send the form to? The Claimant only, the Court only, or both?

Answer (score 1):

A Part 36 offer only needs to be served on the claimant and is effective as of the date of service (see CPR 36.7)